# JS main app which uses routing to show dialogs and such?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, angular, typescript, url-routing

I'm wondering if I can have a JavaScript-based application which has a main "template" as a background/main app of some sorts mixed with some URL routing to show dialogs and such? say, here's a short example:

1. Main app displays google map and whatnot. URL: /#
2. User clicks some menu item and it displays an options dialog. URL: /#options
3. User goes to a sub-options menu. URL: /#options/advanced
4. User closes the main option dialog, back to main app. URL: /#
5. User puts some coordinates in URL and the map locates it.  URL:/#coords/100/100

The main idea here is to keep the map visible (and other stuff that I want to show in that template, too) in the background while using the URL to either display dialogs, forms or even to control the google map itself - BUT that if the user goes to, for example, /#options on first load, the app should load everything and then show the options dialog, okay?

Basically, I'd like to have a "main state" page which contains the most important part of my app, but I'd like to use url-routing for displaying dialogs and executing actions, that users can bookmark in the future and share and so on. I dunno how is this idea/concept called, so that's why I'm asking.

Also, what can I use to archieve something like this? I know this is kind of an open question, but I'm aiming for a JavaScript-based app/framework (TypeScript works too). I don't know if Angular2 + ui-router can do this, or even how should I google this?...

If Angular2+ui-router can do it, then great! but how?. If there are any other frameworks or combinations please provide an example! I've read about vue.js, react.js and so on, but vue.js seemed too simple and react.js still makes me feel uneasy mixing HTML inside the JS files, it just feels unnatural. Thanks in advance for any pointers you can provide! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular 2 can accomplish this. One way would be to have just one component. This component shows your map.

Your logic can watch for changes to the URI parameters and show/hide options accordingly. Since these parameters are not always present, you would use [optional parameters.](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#optional-route-parameters)

While your app is running, you can add event listeners to buttons and links that should change the view state. When the user clicks a `Select City` button, the event listener could direct him to a URI with the appropriate parameter: `;view=dialog;target=city` (Angular 2 uses matrix uri notation by default)

The component would be listening for changes in the parameters and react accordingly.

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
        // this is executed every time new URI parameters arrive
        this.viewType = params['view'];
        this.target = params['target'];

        //todo: update the model to match new parameters
     });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! you're awesome :) I tried to do it the suggested way but I had some issues with Angular 2 so I moved back to Angular 1.5.x and made it using ui-router applying the same concept so I'm marking it as answer. Thanks!